# Convert CheckBoxes into On-Off Button using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've managed to change the status of a product using CheckBox in ASP.NET MVC project with Ajax. Below is the code that I've tried and it worked:

**Model:**

```
public class List
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Details can't be blank")]
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]

   public string Details { get; set; }
   public string Date_Posted { get; set; }
   public string Time_Posted { get; set; }
   public string Time_Edited { get; set; }
   public string Date_Edited { get; set; }
   public string Public { get; set; }
   public int User_Id { get; set; }
   public bool Status { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Is Public")]
   public string PublicPostDisplayText
   {
      get { return Status ? "Yes" : "No"; }
   }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdatePublicPostStatus(int id, bool isPublicPost)
{
    MainDbContext db = new MainDbContext();

    var result = db.Lists.Find(id);
    if (result != null)
    {
       result.Status = isPublicPost;

       db.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.SaveChanges();
    }

   return Json(true);
}
```

**View:**

```
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td id="ID" style="text-align: center;" class="hide">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Id)</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Details)</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Time_Posted)</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Time_Edited)</td>

    @if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      <td style="text-align: center;"><div id="demo"></div> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Status, new { @class = "post-checkbox", data_id = Model.Items[i].Id })</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Auth")/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Id)">Edit</a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Auth")/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Items[i].Id)">Delete</a></td>
      <td class="post-text">@Model.Items[i].PublicPostDisplayText</td>
    }
  </tr>
}
</tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("UpdatePublicPostStatus")';
    $('.post-checkbox').click(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $.post(url, { id: id, isPublicPost: isChecked }, function (response) {
            if (response) {
                var displayText = isChecked ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                row.find('.post-text').text(displayText);
            } else {

            }
        }).fail(function () {
        });
    });
</script>
```

So this is how it looks now as follows:

[image: Sample_Image_For_On_Off_Button]
I am trying to change the CheckBoxes into on-off button. I've tried to use the jQuery toggle plugin replacing the CSS class or id. But seems like I need to do something else. Not sure how to do it. When I click on the button, the value gets changed in the database but unable to show the toggling in the front-end.

**Note:** I just have to change the status of the product from yes to no or no to yes using CheckBoxes and transform the CheckBoxes into On-Off button similar to the below image:

[image: Sample_Image]

Again, I've tried to use jQuery based toggle using some plugin like the following but didn't get it worked:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="Content/jquery.btnswitch.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/jquery.btnswitch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.post-checkbox').btnSwitch({
            //iOS like button
            Theme: 'iOS',

            //On/off text
            OnText: "On",
            OffText: "Off",

            //Values of on/off buttons
            OnValue: true,
            OffValue: false
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? For example, you say that your jQuery based toggle doesn't "work". How? What's happening? Are you getting errors?

Comment: No errors @Chris Pratt. The problem is I am not getting it done like I can get the design but it doesn't toggle whenever I click on the button. The value get changed in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.CheckBoxFor` generates `<input type="checkbox">`. You can't call the btnSwitch function on that. Instead just use a `<div>` or `<span>`.

Comment: I've tried to do so. But I am not sure what's wrong with it. It even doesn't get the design and included all the required files for the `jQuery` toggle.

Comment: I've never used btnSwitch myself so I don't know a great deal about it however I tried and tested this yesterday it worked fine for me. Could you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show me what you've got. Also, have you thought about using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) instead? The documentation looks better and it also appears to support usage on `<input type="checkbox">` so you wouldn't have to change the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @William Robinson. I am trying to do it using server-side and it works just fine in the client-side. OK. I'll try to use `BootStrap Toggle`. If possible, share a tutorial or link on it using server-side with ASP.NET MVC or any other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You said you were unable to show the toggling in the front-end? You're using Ajax here so it's just a case of passing the value back and forth then rendering it as you wish. Honestly doing a jsfiddle without any server side might help you make sense of what ever plugin you decide to use - then take it from there. Unless I've misunderstood something and your having a different issue server side?